# downloaded google heatmap png will not load into ReadMe in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, image, readme

I am writing my first README for a group project and having difficulty getting the API Google Heat Map to appear as an image in the Readme.

For all other pictures I used the below code to save the images to a file folder:

```
plt.gcf()

plt.savefig("images/name_of_file.png")
```

For the Heat Map, I downloaded by clicking the upper left hand corner of the image.

In the ReadMe, my code to display the image looks like:

```
<img src="images/1_drinking_bin_correlation_matrix.png" width="700" height="400">
<img src="images/2_top_5_pie_chart.png" width="700" height="400">
<img src="images/3_part_one_heat_map.png" width="700" height="400">
<img src="images/4_continent_boxplot.png" width="700" height="400">
```

All, the pictures are displaying correctly, excluding the HeatMap - only a blank image appears.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The folder of your `<img>` starts with upper case, but you save it in the folder with lower case.

Comment: @Raguel except Allison says the other images load just fine.

Comment: Make sure the actual file exists through something like finder/file explorer

Comment: @MZ I think in this case there are two folders.